# Prueba unitaria en C# para rellenar un formulario

Tags: c#, formularios, pruebas-unitarias, visual-studio-2019

Tengo que hacer una prueba unitaria para rellenar un formulario de modo automático 200 veces con el fin de que de esta forma se pueda descubrir algún bug o algo por el estilo,  lo que tengo hecho hasta ahora son simples clases que generan datos personales aleatorios los cuales se pondrán en el formulario, simplemente son métodos que devuelven texto todos los métodos funcionan, sin embargo mas que un problema con mi código he llegado a un punto en donde no se como hacer lo que sigue, es decir pasar los datos que tengo guardado al formulario, pensaba hacer un método llamado robot el cual sera quien coloque los datos (el método no existe) aunque igual quizá se pueda hacer de otra forma.
Básicamente mi duda es como podría mandar los  datos a un formulario y como podría interactuar con campos como por ejemplo estado civil que en el caso de que estos sea una lista desplegable de donde se seleccione. Realmente no tengo idea de como hacer eso

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace Rellenador_de_formulario
{
    [TestClass]
    public class FormularioTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Datos datos = new Datos();
            Numero numeros = new Numero();
            Robot llenar = new Robot();

        String name, dadLastname, momLastname, nId, curp, rfc, phoneOne, phoneTwo, direction ;

        for (int i = 0; i<200; i++)
        {
            name = datos.Nombre();
            dadLastname = datos.Apellido();
            momLastname = datos.Apellido();
            nId = numeros.NId();
            curp = numeros.Curp();
            rfc = numeros.RFC();
            phoneOne = numeros.Telefono();
            phoneTwo = numeros.Telefono();
            direction = datos.Direcion();

            Robot.Bot(name, dadLastname, momLastname, nId, curp, rfc, phoneOne, phoneTwo, direction);

        }


    }
}
```

}

Comment: de que tipo de aplicacion estamos hablando? es windows application, wpf, xamarin, porque el concepto de formulario cambia en cada caso

Comment: `Datos` es el formulario que quieres testear ? si es asi que eson esos metodos que accedes, o sea Nombre() Apellido() etc?